# Meteor + Cordova. Import header file from Plugins folder to the Public's folder .m file

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cordova

I've added a cordova plugin to my Meteor-Cordova project. Now I need to include it in the `CDVAppDelegate.m`. I've tried many variants (also tried solutions from other stack answers) but failed to import `EGAnimatedFullScreenImage.h`. How can I correctly import this file?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up successfully importing this `header` file in to another `.m` file located in the `Plugins` directory after `Cleaning` the project, reinstalling this plugin, and removing it from the `Headers > Public`